# Cordova delete page from navigation history

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, navigation

I'm having a bit of a problem here.
I'm making a cordova app, which has a navigation menu.
If the user navigates like this:

-> page one  -> page two -> page one

there will be 2 pages in the history, including an instance of the page one (which is the same the user is seeing right now). If the user goes back, it will be like

| page one | -> page two -> page one

So, if the user pressed back on the page one, he certainly doesn't want to see it again while going out of the app, so I want to remove it from the stack.

Note that i'm not trying to remove the previous page from the history, what I want is to remove all instances of the page I am visiting from the navigation stack.

I hope I explained good enough.
How can this be achieved?

Comment: What you can do is to override the android back button. When he presses it, you can inspect the url and if the user is on page 1 you can force the app to close. Take a look here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#backbutton

Comment: Yes, I was going to make that, and thank you for reminding me, but maybe I didn't explain right.
If I have a history like 
-> page one -> page two -> page three -> page two

When I go the 2nd time to the page two, I want to remove the first instance from the history, so the user doesn't see it again.

Comment: Are you using any framework like angularJS to build your app? Also you might want to take a look at push and replace states: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Comment: I am using cordova AKA phonegap, but not angularJS.
I have already looked at that link but concluded that using window.history.go(-3) (for example), would take a lot of work because I would have to increment some values, everytime I navigate to a new page, so I would be capable to go to the previous instance, instead of opening a new one. Maybe I'm missing something... Thanks a lot ;)